# What is the reason for the ratio of the function to a variable?

Tags: javascript, function, garbage-collection, closures

this not work

```js
function myCounter(){
 let counter = 0;
    function plus(){
        counter++;
        return counter;
    }
    return  plus;
}

console.log(myCounter());
console.log(myCounter());
```

but this work

```js
function myCounter(){
 let counter = 0;
    function plus(){
        counter++;
        return counter;
    }
    return  plus;
}
var add = myCounter();

console.log(add());
```

I know they are different in the syntax.
My main question is:
Why function alone on the console.log does not work and should be attributed to a variable

Comment: What do you mean by ratio here?

Comment: Note your first one is just creating and returning the plus function(twice since you call it twice). You never actually execute that returned function and you dont need the assignment you could do `myfunction()()` though each time you call myfunction you are getting a new function and enclosed scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) concept. Calling a `myCounter` function will return you another function and it will initialize "private" variable `counter` inside, so `myCounter() -> function`.

Of course you can call this way `myCounter()()`, but in this case the "private" `counter` variable will be initialized every call with value 0, and won't be useful.

The solution is to store result of `myCounter()` in variable and call it later, so you will have expected behaviour.

```js
function myCounter(){
  let counter = 0;
  function plus(){
    counter++;
    return counter;
  }
  return  plus;
}

console.log(myCounter()());
console.log(myCounter()());
console.log(myCounter()());

console.log('====')

var add = myCounter();
console.log(add());
console.log(add());
console.log(add());
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function `myCounter` only returns a function reference. It does not call the function `plus`.

**In your first example** you only call the function `myCounter`:

`console.log(myCounter());`

**In your second example** you first call the function `myCounter` that returns a function reference:

`var add = myCounter();`

and then you call the returned function:

`console.log(add());`

**Solution:**

You have to change this line

`return  plus;`

to

`return plus();`

This works:

```js
function myCounter(){
    let counter = 0;
    function plus(){
        counter++;
        return counter;
    }
    return plus();
}

console.log(myCounter());
```

Answer (score 0):

In the second example this line: `var add = myCounter();` makes the `add` var to be only a reference to a function, if you will console log the add var without the brackets, it will print only `[Function]`, but the `console.log(add());` makes the add function to be invoked.

In order to make the first example to work, you can change the return statement of the `myCounter` counter function.

This code make the `myCounter` to return only the `plus` function reference:

```
function myCounter(){
    function plus(){
        //code
    }
    return  plus;
}
```

So in order to make it work you should invoke the `myCounter` twice:

```
console.log(myCounter()());
```

But this make the `plus` function to be invoked when the `myCounter` is invoked (called) from inside the `console.log(myCounter())`:

```
function myCounter(){
    function plus(){
        //code
    }
    return plus();
}
```